# How to group by nested list index

Tags: python, list

I have indexes in a nested list

```
[[1],[2,3][4,5,6]]
```

and I have list of elements

```
['A','B','C','D','E','F']
```

I want to group by the indexes meanining the output would look like this:

```
[['A'],['B','C']['D','E','F']]
```

Comment: Fun exercise! Try breaking the problem into smaller pieces. Consider each of those indexes. Then one of those inner lists. Then the set of nested lists.

Comment: Note that this probably isn't a great fit for stackoverflow. It feels like it may be homework? Have a read of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) first! That'll give you some direction, too. Good luck in your learning!

Comment: Provide the code you have tried so far.

Comment: It seems you are asking for a solution for your homework! It would be much better if you try to figure out a solution then ask with problem/errors you come across.

Comment: Why did you tag pandas?  Are these pd.Series or pd.DataFrames?

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested for loops (but be aware that indexing in python starts with 0):

```py
elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
index = [[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
new = []

for i in index:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        temp.append(elements[j])
    new.append(temp)

print(new)
```

Result:

```
[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Comment: If the index list starts with 1, one can subtract 1 from `j` and get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

[Erna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221433/) works if you know how nested the index list is. If you don't, you can use a recursive function:

```py
def group(el, ind):
    ret = []
    for i in ind:
        if isinstance(i, int):
            ret.append(el[i])
        else:
            ret.append(group(el, i))
    return ret

elements = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
index = [[0], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

print(group(elements, index))
```

Output: `[['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
indices = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
elements = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']

[[elements[i - 1] for i in sublist] for sublist in indices]

# [['A'], ['B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Function (with recursion):

```
def nested_sort(user_indexes, user_list):
    result = []
    if isinstance(user_indexes, list) and isinstance(user_list, list):
        for user_index in user_indexes:
            if isinstance(user_index, int):
               result.append(user_list[user_index])
            elif isinstance(user_index, list):
               result.append(nested_sort(user_index, user_list))    
    return result
```

Example 1.

Input:

```
user_indexes = [[1],[2,3],[4,5,6]]
user_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
nested_sort(user_indexes, user_list)
```

Output:

```
[['B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F', 'G']]
```

Example 2.

Input:

```
user_indexes = [[1],[2,[3]],[4,[5,[6]]]]
user_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
nested_sort(user_indexes, user_list)
```

Output:

```
[['B'], ['C', ['D']], ['E', ['F', ['G']]]]
```